# Later-inserted tags not seen by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have this code in my page:

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function() {
   alert('Hello');
  });
 });
</script>
```

Why doesn't the previous code apply to elements with the class "test" which I add later to the document like this for example:

```
$('body').append('<p class="test">Test</p>');
```

Because what happens is that when I click the previous `<p>` tag nothing happens.

Also, if I have this:

```
<div id="first">Edit me.<div id="second">Save me.</div></div>
```

Can I do what the text describes? that is, controlling the content of the `#first` div without affecting the content of the `#second` div?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `.click()` does only apply a listener for elements that are available in the DOM when the method is executed. You should take a look at [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

With `.on()` you can delegate the event, like this for instance:

```
$("body").on("click", ".test", function() {
   alert('Hello');
});
```

Now any element (current and future) with the class `test` available within your body will have a click-event listener.

Answer (score 3):

live is deprecated as of 1.7, use on

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

try using on() listener:

```
$(document).on("click",".test", function() {

  alert('Hello');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you bind events to elements they only bind to those elements that have already been created. So you need to run the 'bind' command again on the new elements.

Alternatively, you can use `on('click')` which will bind the event to existing and all future elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time you attach your event handler the object doesnt exist yet. You cant subscribe to elements that dont exist. <strike>You can use the Live method for this. 
http://api.jquery.com/live/</strike>

It seems those are deprecated (thanks @Anthony Grist). Use On, or delegate() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$('div').on('click', function()
{
 //Do something
});
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated for more than long enough now for people to know better. `.on()` if you're using jQuery 1.7+, `.delegate()` otherwise.

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated in favour of `on()`.

Comment: Like the manual saysyou should use delegate instead of live nad as of Version 1.7 the function on for live and delegate being deprecated

Answer (score -1):

you should use "on" to bind events with the elements that are added after the script is interpreted.

```
$(document).on("click", selector, function(e){
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to apply the click to later added tags, you should use <strike>live</strike> on

```
$(document).on('click','.test',function() { });
```

EDIT: @Anthony your're right. live is deprecated. Updated the code

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated in favour of `on()`.