# Can jQuery be applied in jQuery generated content?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

I don't know why this is not working.

When a li element is clicked I call a PHP file to get some results back and print them in my page. So far so good.

```
$("li").click(function(){

            var item = $(this).html();
            $.getJSON('fSearch.php',{sTerm: item}, function(data){
                var results='';

                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    results += "<li id='t'>"+item.Description+"</li>";

                });
               $('#ResultsHolder').html("<ul>"+results+"</ul>");

            });

        });
```

The first time I click to a li element all works fine, I get results. Now these results is another set of li's and I want them to behave the same, but when I click on the generated li's the function is not executed..

Why is this happening? Why jQuery does not recognize the dynamically inserted li elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Later-inserted tags not seen by JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990573/later-inserted-tags-not-seen-by-jquery)

Comment: @KrisIvanov `.live()` is deprecated, `.on()` is now the preferred method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use a event shortcut (such as `click`, or `hover`) it will only work for events which are available to the DOM on page load. As you are appending elements dynamically you need to delegate the event listener to an element which is always available in your page.

In the example below, I've used `#ResultsHolder`.

```
$("#ResultsHolder").on("click", "li", function(){
    var item = $(this).html();
    $.getJSON('fSearch.php',{sTerm: item}, function(data){
        var results='';
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            results += "<li id='t'>"+item.Description+"</li>";
        });
        $('#ResultsHolder').html("<ul>"+results+"</ul>");
    });
});
```

That should work for jQuery 1.7+. For an older version of jQuery, use `delegate()`...

```
$("#ResultsHolder").delegate("li", "click", function(){ ...
```

Also, all the appended `li` elements have the `id` of 't'. This will end up with invalid code as ids should be unique. Use a class instead if you want to have a group identifier.

Answer (score 7):

`.click()` is not a live handler, is only binds the event to elements that exist in the DOM at the time of execution. If you want the events to be live, you'll need to look into another handler, such as [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, `.on()` is now the preferred method

Comment: Oh I had no idea, I just started using jQuery. I will try the .on() handler to see if I can get the results.Thanks

Comment: Looks like the jQuery website is down, but Rory's answer has a good snippet of how to use it.

Comment: if you use live(), be sure to call that on your parent element like this...

$("ul").on('click', 'li', function(e) { ...

this will not work...

$("li").on('click', function(e) { ...

Answer (score 1):

When you call ("li").click(), you are binding events to the existing li elements.  When you create new li elements, you need to bind them to the event so the click will work.

So, change your loop to something more like this...

```
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var li = $('li').text(item.Description);
    $(li).click(function(e) {  loadChildren(this); });
    $("#ResultsHolder").append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'li' elements that are added to the page don't have the function bound to their click event handler. You need to use the jQuery live() function to do this.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Basically rather than .click(function(){}) you need to do .live("click",function(){})

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated in favour of `on()`. Even in older versions of jQuery it was slow, and `delegate()` is what you shoud be using instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) : `$(document).delegate("li","click",function(){...})`

Or, the newer version, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `$('li').on("click",function(){...})`

If your li's are in some fixed div, you can make it faster by replacing `document` in the first snippet with the selector of that div; and make the second one `$(SELECTOR).on("click","li",function(){...})`

Comment: Do not use `live()`. `delegate()` is the alternative in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the binding the .click functionality to all li's happened before this new one was created. JQuery has the .on() function, which could solve your issue.

```
$("li").on("click", function(event){
// do functionality
});
```

Comment: This is not a delegated event handler, and will still have the same problem the OP describes using `click()`